# Pass data from DOM to native messaging API

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, chrome-native-messaging

I'm working on a chrome extension that sends the URL of the current tab to a background script via Chrome's [native messaging API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging). This starts an external script which runs youtube-dl to extract the video url and pass it to a player that has hardware acceleration on that platform. This works and the code is here: https://github.com/mad-ady/odroid.c2.video.helper.

I'd like to improve it with the following:

- inject new buttons in the DOM after each video element
- on button press extract the video element's src URL and pass it via the messaging API to the backend for playback

My question is "is this allowed/possible"?
How can I call a function defined in background when I'm in the page's scope?

Comment: To answer your specific questions: "Yes, of course it is" and "You can't call such a function directly. But, you can send a message. Upon receipt, the background script could do what you want." You already appear to know this. What are you really intending to ask?

Comment: Thank you for the tips and confirmation. I wanted to make sure it's not something denied by some security p9licy within chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do that thing.

Also if you need to process click to the button only from your extension, you can do it from content_script without injecting script to the page (it's safiest way, because of you will not attaching anything to the page JS contexts).

### Step by step

Register `content_script` and background script in *manifest.json*:

```
...
"content_scripts": [
  {
    "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
    "js": ["content_script.js"]
  }
],
"background": {
  "scripts": ["background.js"]
},
...
```

Add button to the shared DOM in your *content_script.js* and add event listener in `content_script` JS context for it:

```
...
// You need to modify it for screen with video you want and for support old flash videos too
var blocks=document.getElementsByTagName("video");
for(i=0;i<blocks.length;i++){
  registerButton(blocks[i]);
}

// Add button and process click to it
function registerButton(block)
{
  var video=block;
  var button=document.createElement("input");
  button.type='button';
  button.class='getVideo';
  button.value='Send Video To the player';
  button.addEventListener('click',function(){sendUrlToBg(video.src);});
  blocks[i].parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.append(button);
}

// Send URL to background script
function sendUrlToBg(url)
{
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({"action":"openBrowser","url":url},function(r){
        // process response from background script if you need, hide button, for example
    });
}
...
```

In **background.js** process your URL, send it to embeded app, for example:

```
...
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if("action" in request && request.action == 'openBrowser'){
        // Send message to embeded app
        // ...
        // Send response for content script if you need
        sendResponse({"action":"openBrowserAnswer","status":"OK"});
    }
  }
);
....
```

Thats all! :)

### Read more

1. Chrome runtime sendMessage description:
   https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#method-sendMessage
2. Chrome messaging: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging